# How do you artificially complete a stream?

Tags: swift, combine, flatmap

I have a stream of integers that I need to process using a structure that uses a `CurrentValueSubject` to know whether or not it is allowed to do the processing. Since `CurrentValueSubject` doesn't complete, if I do the processing inside a `flatMap()`, the overall stream (`fooTheBars`) only gets to complete if the stream of integers is empty.

If I comment out the processing part (`.flatMap { bar in fooer.doFoo(with: bar) }`) the stream completes normally because the `CurrentValueSubject` is not involved. But I need it to complete normally after all the items are processed regardless of the number of items.

Output I see:

```
[0, 1, 2]
doing foo with 0
doing foo with 1
doing foo with 2
received value
received value
received value
```

What I want it to output:

```
[0, 1, 2]
doing foo with 0
doing foo with 1
doing foo with 2
received value
received value
received value
received completion // hooray, completion!
```

Output when the stream is empty (completes normally which is what I want):

```
[]
received completion // hooray, completion!
```

If I comment out the processing (`.flatMap()`), everything is fine:

```
[0, 1, 2]
received value
received value
received value
received completion // hooray, completion!
```

How do I modify the code below the comment so that the overall stream completes when all the items finish processing? Is using `CurrentValueSubject` like that an inherently bad pattern?

```
struct Fooer {
    private let readyToFoo = CurrentValueSubject<Bool, Never>(true)

    func doFoo(with item: Int) -> AnyPublisher<Void, Never> {
        readyToFoo
            .filter { $0 }
            .map { _ in () }
            .handleEvents(receiveOutput: {
                print("doing foo with \(item)") // processing
            })
            .delay(for: .seconds(1), scheduler: DispatchQueue.main)
            .eraseToAnyPublisher()
    }
}

func getBars() -> AnyPublisher<Int, Never> {
    let bars = (0..<(Bool.random() ? 0 : 3))
    print(Array(bars))
    return bars.publisher
        .eraseToAnyPublisher()
}

// can't change anything above this comment

let fooer = Fooer()
let fooTheBars = getBars()
    .flatMap { bar in
        fooer.doFoo(with: bar)
    }
    .sink(receiveCompletion: { completion in
        print("received completion")
    }, receiveValue: { _ in
        print("received value")
    })
```

Comment: "Since CurrentValueSubject doesn't complete" Except that it does. Just send a completion. Call `send(completion:)`. Problem solved.

Comment: @matt that would be a bad solution since I wouldn't be able to use `Fooer` to process items anymore. I want to be able to use one `Fooer` multiple times

Comment: Sorry, I stopped reading when I came to the false premise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you only want `doFoo` to publish one value. i.e. the "processing" of a `bar` is complete as soon as `doFoo` publishes one value.

Therefore, you can stop the `doFoo` publisher by just taking the `first()`.

```
.flatMap { bar in
    fooer.doFoo(with: bar).first()
}
```

This produces your intended output. And if `readyToFoo` happens to hold `false` when you call `doFoo`, `doFoo` won't publish. It is only when `readToFoo` sends a `true`, does `doFoo` publishes its first value.

Comment: omg that's genius. thank you so much